# Would it be quicker to use a binary heap to get the top x amount of integers from an array or use quick sort

Tags: c++, quicksort, binary-heap

To get the highest X amount of integers from an array, do you guys think that using a binary heap like this would be quicker:

- binary heap to get the highest integer
- store the highest integer
- remove the highest integer from the array
- repeat until we have the highest X amount from the array

Or would it be faster to just use quick sort and take the top x amount of integers from the array?.

EDIT: I should also add that the array can't stay sorted as it has several variables that we want to sort by, e.g:

```
class cl{
   int var;
   int var1;
   int var2;
};
cl clArr[];
```

So, we can request to get the highest integers from any of the variables.

Writing it down, it seems like a quick sort may be a better idea, although I'd like some opinions please, mostly what would be the fastest option.

Thanks

Comment: What fraction of the total array size is X?

Comment: Can vary depending on the requested amount, it isn't constant. It could be the size of the array, it could be 1 integer.

Comment: Note that you don't (necessarily) need a full quick sort; if one partition is wholly outside of the top *x*, it doesn't need to be sorted further.

Comment: depending on the size of the problem, a simple pass over the data and keeping track of the current top `x` values in a suitable data structure should be best O(n) or close depending on overhead of handling the top value 'list'

Comment: Why not just use `std::nth_element`? Does that not do exactly what you asked?

Comment: @Baldrickk Using a sorted tree of of M elements, the update of the top M takes log M, so complexity is O(N log M). However, the sorted tree may not be cache-friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take an example for both these cases:-

Method 1 (Use Max Heap) :-

```
1) Build a Max Heap tree in O(n)
2) Use Extract Max k times to get k maximum elements from the Max Heap O(klogn)

Time complexity: O(n + klogn)
```

Method 2 (Use quick sort):-

```
1) Sort the elements in descending order in O(nLogn)
2) Print the first k numbers of the sorted array O(k).

Time complexity: O(nlogn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement both of these solutions and do some profiling with real data to find out which is quicker.